# Does any Java IDE has Visual Studio style JIT features, breakpoints, and ability to see the process?

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio-2015, ide

As most of you know, in Visual Studio you can put breakpoints to see what happens while your code is working, change its value if necessary, or execute different line from back or forward as next.

- Is that feature a part of a tech called "JIT Debugging"? From what I understand, JIT means only the ability to compile the code for the operating system, which doesn't have to include the debugging features I talked about.
- Is that kind of features exist in any other Java development IDe, platform or environment as well?

Comment: Did you use Eclipse or Netbeas? or IntelliJ...

Comment: No, I haven't used any of them. Do they have exact same features?

Comment: They are the most powerfull IDEs for Java. And they got a debugger similar to Visual Studio.

Comment: That's called Edit and Continue and you might check other IDE's documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by your video link, [here is how to debug with NetBeans Java IDE](https://youtu.be/-H4C9T1ResQ). Which is an IDE that should have the debugging features that you requested.

Answer (score 1):

This video shows exactly what I was looking for: Java Eclipse is able to do the same type of debugging. Thanks for everyone's efforts.

[How to debug with Eclipse Java IDE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRIGQs817VA&list=PLtVUzTUqnYYqkEa98tGD4-z9I4koJAA_c)